# Write output of `npm run start` to a file

Tags: bash, shell, npm

I'd like to capture the output of `npm run start` in a file (I'm getting a ton of errors and I'd like to have more control over how I sift through the output).

When I try

```
npm run start > log.txt
```

I get a very abbreviated file (8 lines) that ends with `[34mℹ[39m [90m｢wdm｣[39m: Failed to compile.`

When I try

```
npm run start &> log.txt // redirect stderr and stdout to a file
```

I get a similarly abbreviated file (11 lines) that ends with similarly garbled output.

What am I missing?

Comment: what does produce the errors?

Comment: @Ente: upgrading a monorepo to babel 7

Comment: so how does your scripts.start section in package.json look like?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

**This will work**

```js
npm run start 2>&1| tee npm.txt
```

**Explanation:**

`2>&1` will redirect error `stderr` to `stdout` and tee command will write terminal output to file.

Comment: ok. that does produce a file with output, but the output is garbled with all sorts of escape type characters (i think they are color codes).  any way to prevent the color codes with the original command?

Comment: ah. ok got rid of the color codes with `esc=$'\e'` and `sed "s/$esc\[[0-9;]*m//g" log.txt > log2.txt`

Comment: Works for `npm run test` as well.

Answer (score 7):

what worked for me:

```
npm start >> log.txt 2>> log.txt
```

`>> log.txt` to redirect `stdout` to the file

`2>> log.txt` to redirect `stderr` to the file

others use the shorthand `&>>` for both `stdout` and `stderr` but it's not accepted by both my mac and ubuntu :(

**extra:** `>` overwrites, while `>>` appends