# React project inside ASP.NET Core 6 project gives error "The command "npm run build" exited with code -1" in docker

Tags: node.js, reactjs, docker, .net-core

I have a SPA .NET 6 project using React which enjoys Dockerfile for publishing purpose. When I can build the React project using "npm run build" in local computer. Also when I use .NET 6 publish tools in Visual Studio 2022 again it succeeds. However, when I run the following Dockerfile

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 AS base

WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src

COPY ["psreactnet.csproj", "."]
RUN dotnet restore "./psreactnet.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/."
RUN dotnet build "psreactnet.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

RUN apt-get update -yq && apt-get upgrade -yq && apt-get install -yq curl git nano
RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_16.x | bash - && apt-get install -yq nodejs build-essential

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "psreactnet.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "psreactnet.dll"]
```

I get an error

> The command "npm run build" exited with code -1

Moreover, the `.csproj` file is as below:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <TypeScriptCompileBlocked>true</TypeScriptCompileBlocked>
    <TypeScriptToolsVersion>Latest</TypeScriptToolsVersion>
    <IsPackable>false</IsPackable>
    <SpaRoot>ClientApp\</SpaRoot>
    <DefaultItemExcludes>$(DefaultItemExcludes);$(SpaRoot)node_modules\**</DefaultItemExcludes>
    <SpaProxyServerUrl>https://localhost:44412</SpaProxyServerUrl>
    <SpaProxyLaunchCommand>npm start</SpaProxyLaunchCommand>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.ApiAuthorization.IdentityServer" Version="6.0.8" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="6.0.8" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="6.0.8" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI" Version="6.0.8" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaProxy" Version="6.0.8" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational" Version="6.0.8" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite" Version="6.0.8" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="6.0.8" />
    <PackageReference Include="OrchardCore.Application.Cms.Core.Targets" Version="1.4.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="app.db" CopyToOutputDirectory="PreserveNewest" ExcludeFromSingleFile="true" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <!-- Don't publish the SPA source files, but do show them in the project files list -->
    <Content Remove="$(SpaRoot)**" />
    <None Remove="$(SpaRoot)**" />
    <None Include="$(SpaRoot)**" Exclude="$(SpaRoot)node_modules\**" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <Target Name="DebugEnsureNodeEnv" BeforeTargets="Build" Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'Debug' And !Exists('$(SpaRoot)node_modules') ">
    <!-- Ensure Node.js is installed -->
    <Exec Command="node --version" ContinueOnError="true">
      <Output TaskParameter="ExitCode" PropertyName="ErrorCode" />
    </Exec>
    <Error Condition="'$(ErrorCode)' != '0'" Text="Node.js is required to build and run this project. To continue, please install Node.js from https://nodejs.org/, and then restart your command prompt or IDE." />
    <Message Importance="high" Text="Restoring dependencies using 'npm'. This may take several minutes..." />
    <Exec WorkingDirectory="$(SpaRoot)" Command="npm install --force" />
  </Target>

  <Target Name="PublishRunWebpack" AfterTargets="ComputeFilesToPublish">
    <!-- As part of publishing, ensure the JS resources are freshly built in production mode -->
    <Exec WorkingDirectory="$(SpaRoot)" Command="npm install --force" />
    <Exec WorkingDirectory="$(SpaRoot)" Command="npm run build --prod" />

    <!-- Include the newly-built files in the publish output -->
    <ItemGroup>
      <DistFiles Include="$(SpaRoot)build\**" />
      <ResolvedFileToPublish Include="@(DistFiles->'%(FullPath)')" Exclude="@(ResolvedFileToPublish)">
        <RelativePath>wwwroot\%(RecursiveDir)%(FileName)%(Extension)</RelativePath>
        <CopyToPublishDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToPublishDirectory>
        <ExcludeFromSingleFile>true</ExcludeFromSingleFile>
      </ResolvedFileToPublish>
    </ItemGroup>
  </Target>
</Project>
```

Comment: That's an NPM, not ASP.NET Core error. The output of `npm run build  --prod` will contain a ton of info, warning and error messages just like `dotnet build` does. `npm run build` doesn't use `csproj` either, it executes the `build` script in `package.json`.   Have you tried running `npm run build --prod` in the command line? A production build isn't the same as a dev build. If that works on the host but not the container the problem may be missing packages or missing tools. Check the container's console output for messages

Comment: How can I find out which package(s) is missing?

Comment: 'npm run build --prod' and 'npm run build' both work successfully in local computer. Even when I use publish tool of visual studio 2022 both of them work

Comment: You'll have to check the output of the container build. Either check the container's console output or redirect the command's output to a file [as shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57915432/write-output-of-npm-run-start-to-a-file)

Comment: Container cannot be created because of the error. I just can see the output of the terminal which shows Compiled with warnings message

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and I decided to build my react app, directly in the docker and ignore Microsoft dotnet to build my react app.

**Step #1: Disable dotnet from npm install and build on Publish command:**

Open the .csproject file and find the `Target Name="PublishRunWebpack"` tag and comment the section.

```
 <Target Name="PublishRunWebpack" AfterTargets="ComputeFilesToPublish">
    <!-- As part of publishing, ensure the JS resources are freshly built in production mode --><!--
    <Exec WorkingDirectory="$(SpaRoot)" Command="npm install" />
    <Exec WorkingDirectory="$(SpaRoot)" Command="npm run build" />

    --><!-- Include the newly-built files in the publish output --><!--
    <ItemGroup>
      <DistFiles Include="$(SpaRoot)build\**" />
      <ResolvedFileToPublish Include="@(DistFiles->'%(FullPath)')" Exclude="@(ResolvedFileToPublish)">
        <RelativePath>wwwroot\%(RecursiveDir)%(FileName)%(Extension)</RelativePath>
        <CopyToPublishDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToPublishDirectory>
        <ExcludeFromSingleFile>true</ExcludeFromSingleFile>
      </ResolvedFileToPublish>
    </ItemGroup>-->
  </Target>
```

**Step #2: Update the Dockerfile**

I added a step `buildjs` to build my React UI. Then at the final step, I copied the result of `buildjs` to the wwwroot folder of the final image.

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["Tes.Web.BFF/Tes.Web.BFF.csproj", "Tes.Web.BFF/"]
RUN dotnet restore "Tes.Web.BFF/Tes.Web.BFF.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/Tes.Web.BFF"
RUN dotnet build "Tes.Web.BFF.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

#RimaCC
#Build the ReactApp with node official image
FROM node:18 as buildjs
WORKDIR /app
ENV PATH /app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH
COPY "Tes.Web.BFF/ClientApp/" ./
RUN npm ci --silent
RUN npm install react-scripts@5.0.1 -g --silent
#RUN npm run build-themes
RUN npm run build
#End RimaCC

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "Tes.Web.BFF.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
COPY --from=buildjs /app/build ./wwwroot
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Tes.Web.BFF.dll"]
```

Here is why I did this:
Similar to your experience: When I run .NetCore React code on simple Reactjs application, it worked, however on more complex React applications, although the Reactjs App build successfully, I got the same error. Here are the my theories why it does not work and came with this solution:

- **Possibility #1**: Although the React part is building successfully, There are some warning in the build and it cause `npm run build` to exit with a code other than 0. If this is the case, we need to report this to MS so they can fix it in their future releases.
- **Possibility #2**: Installing nodejs and build-essential on MS dotnet sdk image is not enough for building my TypeScript React app. Therefore, I decided to use the `node official image`. This worked perfectly as the asp.net core app is a wrapper around the React App and will serve the final static HTML and JS in wwwroot folder. Moreover, I have a full control over the build process of my React App